# How can I verify that an internal property was set with the correct value?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Here's the piece of code:

```
[HttpPost(UriFactory.FOO_ROUTE)]

public async Task<ActionResult> AddFooAsync([FromRoute]string novelid, [FromBody]AddFoo command)
{
    var novel = await RetrieveNovel(novelid);
    if (novel == null) return NotFound();
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

    command.FooId = Guid.NewGuid();
    novel.AddFoo(command);
    await _store.SaveAsync(novel);

    return Created(UriFactory.GetFooRoute(novel.Novel.NovelId, command.FooId), command);
}
```

How can I verify in a unit test that FooId was indeed set with a NewGuid?

Comment: You are not in control of getting the new id so there is no way for you to confirm that. You could however abstract the creation of the id behind a service you control and can then mock and verify in your test.

Comment: Just check in your database if a new Foo was added as you expected? I'm guessing you can use `RetrieveNovel(novelid)` for that.

Comment: Unit test should really mock any external dependencies, `UriFactory.GetFooRoute` for example. You would then be able to check that the mock was called with appropriate parameters. Should also mock `RetrieveNovel`. this way you can write tests to check all side effects as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) you can verify that an internal property was set like this:

```
  [TestMethod, Isolated]
  public void Test1
  {
      var testFoo = Isolate.Fake.Dependencies<AddFoo>();
      var newGuid = new Guid();
      testFoo.FooId = Guid.NewGuid()
      Isolate.Verify.NonPublic.Property.WasCalledSet(testFoo, "FooId").WithArgument(newGuid);
  }
```

or you can extract the property and assert that it's a Guid:

```
  [TestMethod, Isolated]
  public void Test2
  {
      var testFoo = Isolate.Fake.Dependencies<AddFoo>();
      var fooID = Isolate.Invoke.Method(testFoo , "getFooID");
      Assert.IsTrue(fooID is Guid);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Seperation of concerns is needed.**

I don't exactly know what you're trying to do here. But for me this looks like

Retrieving and load some data

```
var novel = await RetrieveNovel(novelid);
if (novel == null) return NotFound();
if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

Some business logic

```
command.FooId = Guid.NewGuid();
novel.AddFoo(command);
await _store.SaveAsync(novel);
```

Maybe if you seperated your logic you could easily test them.

Also if you just want to test if the FooId Attributes' value changed. Then you should mock the rest. Like Loading the Novel,saving it and the other external dependancies like UriFactory.